# Поиск в google приводит к 503 ошибке при многократном обращении

Tags: c#, http

Нужно много-много раз выдать первую ссылку из гугла програмно.

Вот код, который выдает ссылку по запросу:

```
string uriString = "http://www.google.com/search";
string keyword = "запрос";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nameValueCollection.Add("q", keyword);

webClient.QueryString.Add(nameValueCollection);
string html = webClient.DownloadString(uriString);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nc = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"hJND5c\"]/cite");
return nc[0].InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
```

Но, при многократном обращении, а с недавнего времени и при одиночном, выдает ошибку 503 - сервер не доступен.

Я полагаю, это из-за количества запросов. Вопрос в том, как этой недоступности сервера избежать.

Comment: А) Делать меньше запросов. Б) Пользоваться прокси. Ваш, КО.

Comment: Вы не правильно понимаете ошибку 503 в контексте сервера гугл, он ставит вас в очередь и сл. ответом сервера будет 302 редирект на страницу с каптчей.

Comment: Чтож, хорошо. Выход из этой ситуации есть? Помимо вариантов господина КО

Answer (score 0):

Чтож, попробовал использовать прокси. Способ 1:

```
        string uriString = "http://www.google.com/search";
        string keyword = "запрос";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        nameValueCollection.Add("q", keyword);

        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("87.98.174.157", 3128);            
        webClient.Proxy = wp;

        webClient.QueryString.Add(nameValueCollection);
        string html = webClient.DownloadString(uriString);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nc = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"hJND5c\"]/cite");
        return nc[0].InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
```

Не помог. Способ второй - настроил прокси в IE, и заменил

```
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("87.98.174.157", 3128);            
        webClient.Proxy = wp;
```

на

```
webClient.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Тоже результатов не дал. Если объясните, что я делаю не так - буду весьма признателен.